# Nim variant with minimum number of objects?

Tags: co.combinatorics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory, reading-list

I'm wondering where I can find in the literature (if it exists) a discussion of a Nim variant where we impose the additional condition on Nim that we can remove only up to $c$ objects before the game is over, where $c \in \mathbb{N}$ is a parameter of the game. This is equivalent to imposing the restriction that, if $T_0$ is the initial number of objects, that we never go below $T_0-c$ objects *remaining*.

I've worked out that in a 2-heap version of this Nim variant, the P positions will be any position where the total number of objects $T$ is less than or equal to $T_0-c$, or any position $(x,x)$ where $x > T_0-c$.

Just looking for further reading on something like this.

Comment: The characterization of the N positions in the two heap case looks incorrect, e.g., if c=1 then any non-empty position is an N position.

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole Not sure why you think that. c=1 means we can remove 1 object before the game is over. In a non-empty position, player one will simply remove 1 object from the non-empty pile, thus leaving no moves for the second player. Thus every non-empty position in the c=1 game is in fact P.

Comment: Do you maybe have P and N reversed? Or are you assuming misère rules? If player 1 automatically wins, that is an N position, not a P position. In any event, we agree that the N positions are not the ones you characterize in your question.

Comment: I am not assuming misere - misere is a "if you can not move, you win" ruleset. " If player 1 automatically wins, that is an N position, not a P position" correct. That's why c=1 for non-empty *starting* positions is P - player 1 removes an object, which leaves player 2 with no moves, and thus player 2 loses. The N and P positions for this game depend on the starting position. For example if we start with (5,3), then (5,3) is P, but of course every position arising after one move from (5,3) is N. That's why I've implicitly meant only to characterise which starting positions are N.

Comment: There might be a better way to do it, which is why I'm only asking for further reading.

Comment: I think this is a nice question, unfortunately I don't know any references for it, but you've misunderstood the terminology of the field and make incorrect assertions of fact in the second paragraph.

Comment: You haven't told me why specifically I'm wrong, so I'm afraid your comment isn't helpful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116590/discussion-between-gabriel-c-drummond-cole-and-csstudent).

Comment: To be clear: does this mean that if a heap is size at least $c$, the first player can win by taking $c$ from that heap so that the game is ended?